# Can the energy dissipated in a power-off descent be calculated and expressed in horsepower?

Tags: aircraft-physics, performance-calculation, descent

If the weight in pounds of an aircraft is known along with its sink rate in feet per minute at best power-off glide conditions, can the horsepower being dissipated by drag as the plane descends via gravity be calculated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Horsepower = weight(lbs) * sink_rate(fpm)/(550*60)

It really is that simple.

#### Background

At a constant airspeed glide, kinetic energy isn't changing, only potential energy. So we know that all the energy going into drag is coming from the descent.

A basic law of physics is:

$P = F*v$

where

- $P$: the power
- $F$: the force, in our case the force due to gravity
- $v$: the velocity, in our case the sink rate

The only trick is that we have to make sure that units align. In the case of horse-power, which is **550ft-lbs/s**, we have to convert *fpm* to *fps* (divide by 60) and then scale by 550 to get the answer in HP.

Even better is when we don't use non-standard units. Then there is no conversion factor, because power in Watts is identically Nm/s.

Comment: Most excellent! I had suspected that but wasn't sure whether or not I needed to first convert pounds to slug-furlongs per imperial fortnight, or something equally psychedelic. -NN

Comment: by the way, the sink rate has to be expressed in feet per *second*. -NN

Comment: @nielsnielsen slug-furlongs per imperial fortnight could be called "nielsens"? :)

Comment: I am honored! -NN

Comment: 1 horsepower=550 ft-lbs/sec, not per minute, per [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+of+horsepower&oq=definition+of+horsepower&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l3j0i22i30l6.8947j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) supporting niels nielsen's comment

Comment: @RossMillikan aaaaand that, ladies and gentlemen, is why we must only use metric. :D

Comment: What? And lose the BTU?   Seriously, would the math be the same for water impounded behind a dam, e.g. if the airplane's weight of water fell 500’ through the dam's turbogenerator, is that the same energy as the airplane descending 500’?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, please, lose all of it! Yes, the energy change is identical. Potential energy is simply $mgh$, where $m$ is the mass, $g$ is gravity, and $h$ is the height drop.

Comment: Then there needs to be a Merkel Thermal Unit or something I can say without sounding like I'm talking about something else. Because so many hard thermal problems are made easy to communicate by the BTU.

Answer (score 9):

That power is sink rate x glider weight. If you use m/s for sink rate and newton for weight, you'll get the power in watt. Advantages of SI...

It's easy to understand why it is so. Within a uniform gravitational field with acceleration g, a mass m is pulled down with a force m·g. The potential gravitational energy E at a given height h is E = m·g·h

Now, for an infinitesimal variation of height dh, the corresponding infinitesimal variation of energy is dE = m·g·dh

And if that variation dE takes place in an infinitesimal time dt, the power implied is W = dE/dt = m·g·dh/dt. Since, in our case, dh/dt is the sink speed w, we have that power W = m·g·w

Comment: Not an advantage in this case, because you've got to convert the sink rate shown on your variometer to meters/sec, and the weight of your glider to kg.

Comment: Unless you know both of these things already.  BTW weight is in Newtons, not kg.

Comment: @Frog: Maybe for the pedantic, but I assure you that if you visit Europe (or other metricified) place, and buy things that are sold by weight, the package is almost certainly going to be labeled in kg.  I'm also willing to bet that if you look up the weight of European-built airplanes, it will be given in kg.

Comment: @jamesqf It's true, and may be due to the fact that the kilogram was, in the original definition, the unit of weight. In fact, and until the 1960s (more or less) many calculations were done with the MKS system, where the reference unit was the force, its unit being the kilogram-force or kilopond, (weight of the standard kilogram) and the mass was a derived unit, often called UTM (Unidad Técnica de Masa) or TME (Technische Masseneinheit), the amount of mass accelerated at 1m/s2 by 1 kilogram-force...

Comment: @jamesqf - you're not buy things by weight, but by mass ;)

Comment: @Dominik Szymański: No, I am buying by weight.  For instance, if I get some produce and load it on a typical grocery scale, that scale is measuring weight, not mass.  It's just that on Earth, the two happen to be equivalent.

Comment: @xxavier: See any dictionary for the definition of pedantic :-)

Comment: @jamesqf they absolutely are not equivalent. Weight is about 10 times bigger than mass on Earth, it just happens that scales are giving you mass based on assumption of given gravity. Look up any physics grade school book. Gram (and pound if you wish so) are units of mass. Unit of weight is Newton.
Scale on different planet would be just plainly lying. 1 liter of water by definition contains (in normal conditions, that is temperature and pressure) 1kg of water. However if you put the same amount of water (1 liter) on the scale on mars it would show around 0.39kg and that would be a lie.

Comment: @DominikSzymański You can't compare mass with force, since they are different things.

Comment: Common usage aside, if you want your SI calculations to work then you have to use Newtons as a unit of force